# How to make a foreach loop show something for the first row, middle results, then a special last row result?

Tags: php

I was trying to display the results of this form where when you checkbox a fruit, it shows that fruit, then on the last one it puts a "." period instead of a comma.

It comes down to something in my foreach loop that is causing this.

```
    <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><?php
       $fruitArray = array('orange', 'apple', 'grapefruit', 'banana', 'watermelon');

           if(isset( $_POST['fruit']))
           {  $values = array();



                $i = 0;
                $length = count($_POST['fruit']);
                echo 'Checkbox checked: ';
                foreach ($_POST['fruit'] as $selection) {
                     if ($i == 0) {
                         //first to show
                        echo $selection . ' , '; 
                     } else if ($i == $length - 1) {
                         //last to show
                        echo $selection . '.';
                     }else{
                    echo $selection . ' , ';     
                    $i++;
                }
                }
            }
```

I also was trying this:

```
                    foreach ($_POST['fruit'] as $selection) {

                    echo reset($selection) . " , ";
                    echo current($selection) . " , ";
                    echo end($selection) . " . ";
                }
    ?>

    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Checkbox selection using PHP (using PDO) and MySQL v2</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h2>Pick your most favourite fruits:</h2>
          <form name="fruitcheckbox" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
             <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange"> Orange
             <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple"> Apple
             <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit"> Grapefruit
             <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="banana"> Banana
             <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="watermelon"> Watermelon
             <br>
             <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn_save">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added in here also if you only have 1 row, this is what you put in here:

```
                $i = 0;
                $length = count($_POST['fruit']);

                //if one row
                if ($length == '1'){
                    foreach ($_POST['fruit'] as $selection) {
                        echo 'Checkbox checked:  '. $selection . '.';
                        echo 'Rows counted ' . $length;
                    }
                }else{
                    echo 'Checkbox checked: ';
                    foreach ($_POST['fruit'] as $selection) {
                        echo $selection;  //current fruit
                        if (each($_POST['fruit'])){ 
                           echo ", "; //current rows put a comma after fruit

                        }else if (!each($_POST['fruit'])) {
                            echo ".";//last row put period instead of comma
                        }                       
                    }
                    echo 'Rows counted ' . $length;
                }
```